# Move center of a view using pangesture by updating center constraints

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I am working on an app where the user can drag the view with finger and change its center point.

But I am facing an issue if I create that dragging view with auto layout.

Currently, I am applying its height width and center constraints programmatically.

But there is no way to update the center constraint to a specific point in a view.

This is how I am applying center constraint with respect to its   SuperView.

```
    // Set center constraints
labelControl.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
labelControl.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(this.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;


    // On Pangesture
this.AddGestureRecognizer(new UIPanGestureRecognizer((recognizer) =>
                {
                    CGPoint translation = recognizer.TranslationInView(recognizer.View.Superview);

                    CGPoint newCenter = new CGPoint(lastLocation.X + translation.X, lastLocation.Y + translation.Y);

                    //this.Center = newCenter; // This does not work as we have applied constraints.

                    CenterXConstraint.Constant = newCenter.X;
                    CenterYConstraint.Constant = newCenter.Y;
                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSLayoutConstraint[] list = this.Constraints;
foreach(NSLayoutConstraint c in list)
{
     if(c.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX)
     {
          XConstraint.Constant = newCenter.X;                       
     }
     if (c.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY)
     {
           YConstraint.Constant = newCenter.Y;
     }
}
```